Behaviour of TCP setting ForceWS (Windows)
I'm in the process of setting up a new Windows Server 2022 to replace a very old (2012 R2) one. When looking through the settings I can see that the new and the old server have different settings for the TCP setting ForceWS. According to Microsoft documentation this setting:

"Specifies an array of values that determine whether to force window
scaling for retransmission"

I have a hard time understanding exactly what this setting does. I think I get the basics of window size and scaling and how it is affected by acks and retransmissions, but obviously I have some kind of gap.
Could someone explain it to me and your experiences of how this setting has affects your servers?

The TCP window scale option increases the maximum receive window size from 64 KiB to ~1 GiB. The option is necessary for high-speed, high-latency transmissions - when the path's bandwidth-delay product exceeds 64 KiB (long fat network LFN).
Options are negotiated during the initial three-way handshake, so force window scaling for retransmission is not clear to me.
See RFC 7323 for details.

Thank you for the answer. Glad I'm not the only one who think it is not clear
